# How to quickly sample points according to the given distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, sampling

Consider the following points sampler:

```
weightscomp = 
 Compile[{{data, _Real}, {power, _Integer}, {T, _Real}}, Module[{vals},
   vals = data;
   vals^power Exp[-vals/T]
   ]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
DistrSampler[nparticles_, T_, power_] := Module[{(*pts,weights,sample*)},
  pts = RandomReal[{0, 15 T}, Max[10*nparticles, 10^5]];
  weights = weightscomp[pts, power, T];
  sample = RandomSample[weights -> pts, nparticles];
  sample
  ]
```

It samples points according to the distribution $x^{\text{power}}\exp[-x/T]$, where `power>0` is some power and $T>0$.

I want generated points to return a reasonably large value from Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. For the test example, I do

```
Tval=3.;
samples = 
  DistrSampler[10^5, Tval, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Show[LogLogPlot[1.1feq[e],{e,0,50}],Histogram[samples,100,\
"ProbabilityDensity",ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}]]*)
feq[e_] = (e^2*Exp[-e/Tval])/
  Integrate[x^2*Exp[-x/Tval], {x, 0, 15. Tval}]
theoreticalDist = ProbabilityDistribution[feq[e], {e, 0, 15. Tval}]
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[samples, theoreticalDist]
```

and get 0. If I replace `Max[10*nparticles, 10^5]` with `Max[100*nparticles, 10^5]` in `DistrSampler`, I start getting non-zero values, but very random - from 10^-3 to 0.99. If I replace 100 with 1000, I will not change the situation much.

Could you please tell me if there is another way of sampling points that would maximize the result of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?

I tried a method using CDF, but the problem is that the inverse CDF cannot be found:

```
norm[T_, power_] = 
 Integrate[e^power Exp[-e/T], {e, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> power > 0 && T > 0]
cdf[Eval_, T_, power_] = 
 1/norm[T, power] Integrate[e^power Exp[-e/T], {e, 0, Eval}, 
    Assumptions -> power > 0 && T > 0 && Eval > 0] // Simplify
uEval[x_] = Solve[cdf[Eval, T, 2] == u, Eval]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available
> to Solve.

Comment: Is this a `GammaDistribution`? Can you use `RandomVariate`?

Comment: @mikado : thanks, I am an idiot.

Comment: Far from it - it's easy to go from a name to a PDF.  The other way is far more difficult.

Comment: @mikado is right on the money.  It appears to be a `GammaDistribution[power + 1, T]`.